# Keep disposing and increase CommandTimeout for some methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to get rid of repeating line of code:

```
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

This is my repository class:

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180; // repeat 1
            return context.Students.ToList();
        }            
    }

    public void InsertStudents(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180; // repeat 2
            context.Students.AddRange(students);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    
    public Student GetStudentByID(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            return context.Students.Find(id);
        }
        
    }
}
```

I thought that [I can do it like that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application):

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private SchoolContext context;

    public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return context.Students.ToList();
    }

    public void InsertStudents(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        context.SaveChanges();          
    }
}
```

However, in my view, this  approach is not good as it does not close database connections. This approach does not dispose any resources.

It is not desirable to increase timeout for the entire Entity Framework entities. Increase of timeout is just necessary for this class.

Is it possible to get rid of duplication of code and keep disposing?

Comment: Put it ion your connection string -> "Data Source=MyPc;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=180;"

Comment: @Shanie thank you for your advice, I forgot to say that it is not desirable to increase timeout for the all entities. Thanks!

Comment: @Shanie that is a connection timeout, not command timeout.

Comment: @Crowcoder what's the difference?

Comment: @Shanie connection timeout configures how long to try to connect to the database. Command timeout is how long to run commands (queries).

Comment: @Crowcoder So command timeout happens after connection timeout?

Comment: @Shanie two distinct things, but yes, since you have to connect before you can execute.

Comment: @Learner Why not just have a GetContext() method that does what ever needs to be done to the context and then passes it on to you.

Comment: @Shanie could you show please how it can be done through `GetContext()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the CommandTimeout in your DbContext's constructor

```
public MyDbContext() : base()
{
  this.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
}
```

Or add a GetDbContext() method to your StudentRepo

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private SchoolContext GetDbContext()
    {
       var db = new SchoolContext();
       db.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
       return db;
    }

    public IList<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        using (var context = GetDbContext())
        {
            return context.Students.ToList();
        }            
    }

    public void InsertStudents(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        using (var context = GetDbContext())
        {
            context.Students.AddRange(students);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    
    public Student GetStudentByID(int id)
    {
        using (var context = GetDbContext())
        {
            return context.Students.Find(id);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response! However, this approach increases `CommandTimeout` for all entities. Is it possible to set `CommandTimeout` and  use `using` in every repository method like in the first approach of my question?